# where the program that has nothing to do with View and Controller should be placed?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm planning to create a program in ruby that will go to a directory to see if there any xml files uploaded, and if there's any, it will read it nodes and import them into corresponding tables of mysql. Can anyone tell me, where such sort of programs should be stored? They have nothing to do with View and Controller. As it deals with mysql, should it be saved under models folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is direct data manipulation yes it is closer to model than view or controller. However, is this built into an existing application or is it a standalone project?

Quite often ruby developers will put functionality like this in the `lib` folder of an existing project, since it's not strictly part of the MVC frame, it's more like 'support' functionality.

Comment: Hi @Matt! What do you mean under "standalone project" ? :) I'm going to create a project, and this program will be a part of it...

Comment: `lib\tasks` is used for rake tasks - tasks that would normally be run by command line rather than in the app itself. If that suits your usage then by all means go for it! Here's a bit of info about rake tasks: http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial

Comment: As I'm new to RoR, I have no idea if rake what I need. I just need to create a program that will run, let's say once an hour. So, it's like a scheduled task...

Comment: That sounds absolutely like an ideal candidate for a rake task :)

Comment: Great @Matt! I will dive into rake stuff :)